# Two primary keys & auto increment

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

I have a MySQL table with two fields as primary key (ID & Account), ID has AUTO_INCREMENT.
This results in the following MySQL table:

```
 ID    |  Account
------------------
 1     |     1
 2     |     1
 3     |     2
 4     |     3
```

However, I expected the following result (restart `AUTO_INCREMENT` for each Account):

```
 ID    |  Account
------------------
 1     |     1
 2     |     1
 1     |     2
 1     |     3
```

What is wrong in my configuration? How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the create table statement and what engine are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Functionality you're describing is possible only with `MyISAM` engine. You need to specify the `CREATE TABLE` statement like this:

`CREATE TABLE your_table (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
account_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(account_id, id)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;`

Answer (score 0):

If you use an innoDB engine, you can use a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `your_table_before_ins_trig` BEFORE INSERT ON `your_table`
FOR EACH ROW 
begin
declare next_id int unsigned default 1;

  -- get the next ID for your Account Number
  select max(ID) + 1 into next_id from your_table where Account = new.Account;

  -- if there is no Account number yet, set the ID to 1 by default
  IF next_id IS NULL THEN SET next_id = 1; END IF;

  set new.ID= next_id; 
end#
```

Note ! your delimiter column is # in the sql statement above !

This solution works for a table like yours if you create it without any auto_increment functionality like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `your_table` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Account` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`Account`)
);
```

Now you can insert your values like this:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (`Account`) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO your_table (`Account`, `ID`) VALUES (1, 5);
INSERT INTO your_table (`Account`) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO your_table (`Account`, `ID`) VALUES (3, 10205);
```

It will result in this:

```
 ID    |  Account
------------------
 1     |     1
 2     |     1
 1     |     2
 1     |     3
```